# I get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when I try to use certbot for let´s encrypt in more than one domain

Tags: apache, certificate, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am following the recommendations of [Digital Ocean to configure several SSL certificates in Let´s Encrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) for more than one domain. Both domains have www subdomains.

The first domain I have configured with SSL is diesanromero.dev and the subdomain www.diesanromero.dev is also configured correctly. I followed the same steps for the freebooks.dev domain and everything turned out perfect, but when I try to use the www subdomain I get the following error:

```
Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.freebooks.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID 

Subject: freebooks.dev

Issuer: Let's Encrypt Authority X3

Expires on: Aug 12, 2020

Current date: May 14, 2020
```

Both subdomains are redirected to their respective domains. I renew the certificates and I don't get any console error, but when I try to enter www.freebooks.dev again I get the same error. Both www and @ records point to the same IP. Also both domains point to the same IP in /etc/hosts.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: hi @Diesan did you solve this error